# python 3.6 // Update pyodbc

Tags: python, batch-file, pip, anaconda, pyodbc

I would like to upgrade a module in python called "pyodbc". 
I use python 3.6 with spider in Anaconda and my version of "pyodbc" is **4.0.22** and the one of my coworker is **3.0.16**.
I would like to upgrade to **4.0.23**.

I tried with a batch file :

```
C: 
cd path to Anaconda3
python -m pip install --user -U pyodbc
```

and I tried manually with the anaconda navigator but nothing works. It's always for me **4.02.22** unfortunately.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the version in the command: python -m pip install --user -U 'pyodbc==4.0.23' --force-reinstall

Comment: It says "successful" but when I go to Anaconda navigator and I go to check the version of pyodbc. It's still 4.0.22.

Comment: Maybe do you think that the problem could be from the part "--user" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Anaconda, you can go for **conda**

```
python -m conda install --upgrade pyodbc
```

or

```
python -m conda install --upgrade pyodbc=4.0.23
```

Since conda is a package manager for any software (installation, upgrade and uninstallation), it will resolve the issue you are facing, which is mostly due to conflicting site-packages such as sqlalchemy, older versions on pyodbc, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's all good now. I will use conda now and not pip anymore.